# Private Set property not retaining its new value

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, android-intent, xamarin.android

Working on a problem for a test application I am building, and I can't seem to work out what to do. The app is essentially a questionnaire that is to be passed between two different people using the same device.

However, when I have a private setter for CurrentQuestion, the value never stays modified when being sent across to the new version of the activity. It always retains its original value of 1 (all other values stay modified though). When debugging though, I do see the value of the property increment by 1, it is just not retained.

As soon as I remove the private setter this resolves itself and it increments like normal, but I know this is bad practice, so I would like to find the correct way to do it.

Any help or guidance would be much appreciated, as I feel like I have tried a huge variety of different methods with no luck.

Comment: Seems like it should work. What happens if you place them separately. Move "myQuiz.NextQuestion();" to the top of OnCreate and move "Question question = repository.GetQuestionById(myQuiz.CurrentQuestion);" to the bottom of OnCreate. Perhaps the value is being passed through before the computation completes?

Comment: I had thought of this before, but moving them do different pleases within the OnCreate doesn't seem to be helping the situation at all.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo so that we can test with it?

Answer (score 2):

Setting an auto-poroperty like this assumes that all access and modification to that property will be done directly though the property itself, as opposed to using a method like you're doing to increment this property. Based on what you're doing here I would recommend this possible solution to your problem.

Set a backing field for the property and increment that in your `NextQuestion` method.

```cs
private int _currentQuestion;
public int CurrentQuestion => _currentQuestion;

public void NextQuestion()
{
    _currentQuestion++;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference, still ends up returning to the original value.

Comment: Weird, but `public int CurrentQuestion { get; set; }` works just fine for you?